# Why did Ultron choose Sokovia?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*

> Ultron turned part of Sokovia into a meteorite which he planned to use to cause humanity's extinction

My question is, what made him choose Sokovia as a location for this nefarious scheme? Is it because Baron von Strucker's HYDRA base was there? If this was mentioned in the film and I missed it, please forgive me.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it was simply because the location was convenient. Ultron took over the Hydra base and conducted his operations from there.

Comment: @Richard: I thought you had said (in a question a couple of months ago) that it was because of the exotic metals under the city, which were necessary to turn a city-destroying asteroid strike into a world-destroying explosion?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I thought so originally. On reflection, it seems like Ultron buries vibranium throughout the city's foundations. That's what Thor and Iron Man cause to explode by backing up the engine.

Comment: He knew that the country was fictional and thus he wouldn't be pissing anyone off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### He wanted access to Hydra's experiments

From the junior novelization of *Age of Ultron*:

> The twins went back with Ultron to Strucker’s fortress, where they
>   were astonished to see many more robots, all refining various
>   experiments Strucker had been working on.

One such experiment might have been related to the synthezoid body that Ultron made, which ultimately became the Vision. This was a high priority for him, so it would make sense that he would want to search through what Hydra knew about it.

> “You look like Strucker’s robotic experiments,” said Pietro. “But they
>   didn’t work.”
>
> “Not for him, they didn’t,” Ultron acknowledged. “Strucker had the
>   engine, but not the spark.”

Comment: Awesome source!

Answer (score 7):

## He needed the resources

[image: Ultron drones in the lab]

I believe after exhausting/discarding the peacekeeping bots, he needed somewhere to

> 1. Manufacture enough drones.
>  2. Create his faux-asteroid; a fauxsteroid, with which he intended to destroy humanity

He was unable to do point 2. From a decentralised location as

> JARVIS was blocking his access to the nuclear launch codes.

Not only does the good Baron's lab have advanced Hydra technology,  I also think it's got Chitauri tech from the first film.

No where else offers that in such a secluded location,  in such an easily overlooked country.